# How to find only text2 in iframe and add a class to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

iframe

```
<iframe id="nameFd" style="width:100%;height:300px" src="/resource/"></iframe>
```

iframe content

```
<a class="rsrt">text1</a>
<a class="rsrt">text2</a>
<a class="rsrt">text1</a>
<a class="rsrt">text2</a>
```

jquery

```
$('#nameFd').load(function(){

        var iframe = $('#nameFd').contents();

        if(iframe.find(".rsrt").text() == 'text2').addClass('close');
});
```

but does not work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var iframe = $($('#nameFd')[0].contentWindow.document.body);
```

An iframe is a separate document, so its DOM is not part of the parent document's DOM. `contentWindow` gets the iframe's global object which contains its DOM.

This will only work if the iframe and parent document have same origin

---

`if(iframe.find(".rsrt").text() == 'text2').addClass('close');` is not valid Javascript.
I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
iframe.find(".rsrt:contains('text2')").addClass('close');
```

Comment: Does not work, the class is not added, they have one domain

Comment: @Sentimo Hmm, is `if(iframe.find(".rsrt").text() == 'text2').addClass('close');` your actual code? That's not even proper syntax

Comment: Maybe I was wrong, but I did not think of anything else

Comment: Does not work, alert outputs text1text2text1text2, respectively, there is no comparison, alert(element.text())

Comment: @Sentimo OK now I understand what you're trying to accomplish. You tried to select a specific element using native `if` but that doesn't work, you either have to iterate over all elements or use jQuery's `:contains` selector. I've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks, I did through each ()